# Import Bootstrap styles in Angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I import bootstrap into my angular 2 project? I have the bootstrap package in the nod_modules directory.
I do this in a component file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import 'bootstrap';
```

But the page gets stuck in the loading...

Comment: 'gets stuck' doesn't explain anything.

Comment: The page gets the GET http://localhost:3000/bootstrap 404 (Not Found) error and Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/bootstrap(…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this lines in you main html to install:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng2-bootstrap/x.x.x/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If you want use it in your component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Alert} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
```

This is de complete documentation for ng2-bootstrap:
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap

Comment: Ok, so the package named 'bootstrap' is not needed? The one needed is the 'ng2-bootstrap' ? So I have to install it via npm and then import it?

Comment: You'll need both `ng2-bootstrap` and `bootstrap` packages installed. ng2-bootstrap, if you choose to use it, is just a wrapper for the bootstrap elements/stylings.  Otherwise, you just include the `<link>` to the bootstrap css file in your `index.html` and you can use all the bootstrap classes in your templates

Answer (score 0):

For those that need a solution for Angular 6+:

1. Install bootstrap via npm
   `npm install bootstrap jquery popper.js`
2. In your angular.json find your `"styles"` and `"scripts"` array and add the paths found in the example below:
3. Restart your local server and refresh your browser.
   `ng serve`

Example:

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
],
```